# Magento 2 Controller response very slow

Tags: magento2, controllers, slowbackend

I've written an ajax call to get some user specific content. But I found that the response of the ajax call is very slow. Indeed, I found that this is due to the slow response of the controller class. The controller class takes at least 2 seconds to give a empty json respnse while the controller is just a simple controller to handle the ajax call.

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Program;

class TestAjax extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Forgot customer account information page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute() {
        $testing= null;

        $arr = array('testing' => $testing);
        $jsonData = json_encode($arr);
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($jsonData);
        $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    }

}
```

Comment: Disabling the cache has a sense for some development tasks only & Caching definitely should be enabled in production mode

Comment: Are you saying this controller action is specifically much slower than all other controllers on the same install?

Comment: Try do it more in magento way, like this, maybe it will be faster:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99358/magento2-how-to-get-json-response-from-controller

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I have also use the Ajax in magento2 and getting very slow response from controller

My Code is:

```
var param = {
    dDate: datem,
    user: <?php echo json_encode($username); ?>,
    courseid: <?php echo json_encode($courseid); ?>
};
 //var param = 'ajax=1&date='+datem+'&arr123='+jQuery.parseJSON(<?php echo json_encode($timeArr2,true); ?>);
 jQuery.ajax( {


url: '<?php echo $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(); ?>/wlcms/index/',
data: param,
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json'

}).done(function(a) { 

     jQuery('#test').show();
    // alert(json_decode(a));                               
     jQuery('#test').html(a);
});
```