# Magento 2 TTFB is very large for a JSON response from a simple controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, response

It takes about 1.5s to show the result on Chrome (1.X seconds are TTFB) according to record of Chrome's network tool.
My Magento is using redis for caches, and the caches are turned on.
How come the controller taking so long time to response?

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;

class GetHealthStatus extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Customer order history
     * return json
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
   public function execute()
    {
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $resultJsonFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory'); 
       $result = ['status'=>'OK'];
       return $resultJsonFactory->create()->setData($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99358/magento2-how-to-get-json-response-from-controller

Comment: Tried, but no difference.