# How to use \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory for Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, json-response

This post is related to this [Magento2 - How to get JSON response from Controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99358/magento2-how-to-get-json-response-from-controller)

What I am trying to do is to format the **`json response of my custom web API`**, but it seems **`\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory`** doesn't seem to work in Magento 2.3

Here's my implementation:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory  */
protected $resultJsonFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    ...
}
```

And implemented it like this:

```
$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
$result->setData(['message' => 'test']);
return $result;
```

And the result (Just a blank bracket):

```
[]
```

Additional solution made:
Tried to implement `\Zend_Json::encode()` and `json_encode` but getting this result:

```
"{\"message\":\"test\"}"
```

Instead of (expected result/prettified json response):

```
{
    "message": "test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
$myArray = [];
$myArray['message'] = 'test';
$result->setData($myArray);
return $result;
```

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: same I got blank brackets

Comment: can you try after `cache:flush`?

Comment: sure. I will ..let me check now

Comment: just did it now and getting the same result

Comment: try this `$myArray=array("message" => "test");` instead of `$myArray = [];` 
 `$myArray['message'] = 'test';`

Comment: tried it after cache flush, still the same result

Comment: can you check the log if it's printing anything?

Comment: yeah I checked it now nothing in there

Answer (score 0):

In your controller,

```
protected $jsonFactory;

public function __construct(
      \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
      \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
) {
      parent::__construct($context);
      $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
 }

 public function execute()
 {
     $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
     $messages = [];
     $messages[] = __('Your message.');
     return $resultJson->setData([
           'messages' => $messages
     ]);
 }
```

Comment: just tried it really quick and got the same result

Comment: what is the result you are getting?

Comment: still, blank brackets

Comment: How you are trying to get that message?

Comment: I'm using postman

Answer (score 0):

In my extension I post to ajax controller and response is in json

https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/master/Controller/Index/Submit.php#L107-L110

https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml#L95

Works for me. Bit different to what you've tried so far. I hope it helps. Good luck.

*Update*

Have you tried accessing `getResponse` from context

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerApprove/blob/master/Plugin/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php

```
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_response = $context->getResponse();
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $context->getResultRedirectFactory();
        $this->resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I got an error about getResponse() method maybe because I am implementing it in a model, not in a controller. I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get blank brackets is because webapi has its own renderer which is trying to convert whole `Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json` object into json.

You should return just the data instead and renderer will convert it.

**Use this**

```
return ['message' => 'test'];
```

**Instead of this**

```
$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
$result->setData(['message' => 'test']);
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, i found that JsonFactory doesnt work for me in webapi, so there is another solution to return a json with the `Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response` class.

**Try this:**

```
$result = json_encode(['message' => 'test']);
return $this->response->setBody($result)->sendResponse();
```